# Getting access to assets downloaded by browser while loading a website

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there any way to access files (css, js, fonts, images) that were downloaded by browser while loading a website (via HTTP with URLs retrieved from html documents) in javascript?

I want to have a File object / content / blob in js for each asset that browser has downloaded. Is there any way to do this or do I have to parse html first and download all the files via javascript ?

Comment: Some pseudo code might help (me at least :P)

Comment: Let me break it down for you.

Comment: 1. You access the website by providing URL in the browser. Browser downlaods the HTML document on that URL. 2. Browser parse the documents and queues all the assets URL to download (css, images, js, fonts, etc) 3. Browser downloads each file and renders it on the website. 4. Here I want to access these files somehow from client side in javascript as a text/blob ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: If the site has already been loaded, the files in question (i.e. CSS/JS/images) will have been cached by the browser, and so re-requesting these assets will typically load them from the cache.

However, this all occurs transparently, and you will not be able to tell the difference between a remotely fetched file and a file loaded from a cache.

If you can explain what you want to achieve by having File object access, then perhaps I can make an alternative suggestion.

Comment: Well, it does not matter if the file was actually downloaded or fetched from internal browser cache. I want to access the file anyway, no matter how the browser got it.

Comment: Shortly, I want to send the file via webrtc data channel

Comment: After a little digging, it seems like File objects are only available when requesting files from the local filesystem. Instead, you're gonna want to use [binary data over XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). Hopefully this points you in the right direction!